# Move constructor versus copy constructor behavior on class with no member variables

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics

```
class NullTimer {
 public:
  inline static bool changePeriod (const size_t) { return false; }
  inline static void dispose (void) {}
  inline static bool isActive (void) { return false; }
  inline static void reset (void) {}
  inline static void start (void) {}
  inline static void stop (void) {}
};

template <
  Timer
>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo (
    const Timer & t
  ) :
    _t(t)
  {}

  Foo (
    Timer && t
  ) :
    _t(t)
  {}
 private:
  Timer t;
};

Foo<NullTimer> bar(NullTimer());
```

Utilizing the move constructor of the templated type is causing bizzare behavior in my embedded application (*hard to diagnose because of the embedded nature*). If I do it in two steps (utilizing the copy constructor), then it behaves as expected.

```
NullTimer nt;
Foo<NullTimer> bar(nt);
```

Can someone explain the fundamental difference(s) in the mechanism of the constructors, and why it would cause different behavior?

Comment: Good ol' Most vexing parse.

Comment: Most vexing indeed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo<NullTimer> bar(NullTimer());` is a function declaration; it declares a function named `bar`, which returns `Foo<NullTimer>`, and has a unnamed parameter that is a function pointer returning `NullTimer` and taking nothing.

You can change it to

```
// since C++11
Foo<NullTimer> bar(NullTimer{});
Foo<NullTimer> bar{NullTimer()};
Foo<NullTimer> bar{NullTimer{}};

// before C++11
Foo<NullTimer> bar((NullTimer()));
```

See [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: `Foo<NullTimer> bar((NullTimer()))` also works, though I think the forms with braces should be preferred for readability reasons.

Comment: @Brian Yes, it's the general workaround before C++11.